# Any possible ideas that will help me solve this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, approximate-integration

I have an integral $$I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dz}{r^{m/2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a\cos^2\theta+b\cos\theta\cos\alpha+c\cos^2\alpha+d}},$$ where$$r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2= R^2+z^2$$ and $$\cos\theta=\hat{r}.\hat{z}$$ and $$\cos\alpha=\hat{\zeta}.\hat{z},$$ where $\zeta$ is a specified fixed direction. $a, b, c, d$ are constants and $m>1$ is a rational number. Any idea on any approximation method to solve this integral would be highly welcomed. Please share your ideas.

Comment: So $\theta=\theta(z)$, right?

Comment: Well that is one thing which is confusing me. It seems that $\theta=\theta(z)$, but since unit vector towards z is fixed, I also think that there is a possibility that $\theta$ is independent of $z$. I am really confused.

Comment: Assuming this is in spherical-polar coordinates, this seems to be a line integral along the path $r=R^2+z^2$, $\phi=phi_0$, and $0\leq z\leq \infty$. If that's the case, then certainly $\hat{r}$ will change as function of $z$. In fact, $\theta$ will go from $\pi/2$ to $0$. As for how to solve this, I don't know right now, but maybe looking at what it means geometrically will help.

Comment: Right. I think that makes sense. I have slightly modified the integration limit. With the new limit, $\theta$ should change from 0 to $\pi$.